# How to provide content type in module for Drupal 8?

Tags: nodes

How do I write a module that provides a content type in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 8):

For a module name `my_module` and a content type called `awesome_page`, the directory structure would look like:

- my_module/

  - my_module.info.yml
  - config/install/

    - node.type.awesome_page.yml

And the file contents would be:

`my_module.info.yml`:

```
name: Awesome page content
type: module
description: 'Add awesome content type.'
core: 8.x
dependencies:
  - node
```

`node.type.awesome_page.yml`:

```
type: awesome_page
name: 'Awesome page'
description: '<em>Awesome</em> pages are a little better than other pages.'
help: ''
new_revision: false
display_submitted: true
preview_mode: 1
status: true
langcode: en
```

For several other examples, find all modules in core that provide new content types: `find . -iname "node.type*"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Drupal Console](http://drupalconsole.com/), this will automatic ask you for couple question an generate the content type (entity type) for you on a module.

Here is the command that you need to `generate:entity:bundle [options]`

Comment: Drupal Console just blew my mind - reminds me of all the PHP Cake Bake stuff.